# Header/ Footer in MVP GWT project

Tags: java, gwt, mvp

How i m suppose to create header and footer for my MVP GWT application? 
For example, the design i was used with gwt but without mvp was, having header, footer and content panel which i used to display current view. Header and footer was singleton instances loading once in the begging.

```
Header instance Singleton;
Footer instance Singleton;
Content instance Singleton;
Content.getContent(Set current view);
```

How could do the same following mvp model?

Thanks

Edit
The MVP implementation i m using is gwt presenter.

Comment: Places/Activities which are included in gwt 2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good article on this topic:  [Using GWT MVP with multiple views on the page](http://www.rubiconred.com/blog/using-gwt-mvp-with-multiple-views-on-the-page/)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a skeleton view, which includes a header, a footer, and a content panel. Once the skeleton view has loaded, you set the skeleton view's content panel as the panel to contain views.

In code, it looks like this:

```
Place targetPlace = historyMapper.getPlace(History.getToken());
if (targetPlace == null) targetPlace = defaultPlace;
placeController.goTo(skeletonPlace);
activityManager.setDisplay(skeletonView.getContentPanel());
// potentially show a "Loading.." view here
placeController.goTo(targetPlace);
```